# How to Create User Defined function in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to create a function in jmeter and need to call this function by using `Function helper Dialog`,and When I google regarding this ,I found one link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/jmeter-custom-function-implementation.html

but still the created function is not appeared in the dialog box.

Is any one will help m regarding this ??

Thanks in advance....

And my Jmeter log for this is :

```
2014/12/18 10:48:00 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2014/12/18 10:48:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\user.properties 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\system.properties 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.12 r1636949 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_51 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows XP 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=x86 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=5.1 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.206.0.106 Name: himanshuj2 FullName: himanshuj2.newvisionsoftware.com 
2014/12/18 10:48:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2014/12/18 10:48:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2014/12/18 10:48:03 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2014/12/18 10:48:04 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
2014/12/18 10:48:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2014/12/18 10:48:06 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2014/12/18 10:48:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file E:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2014/12/18 10:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2014/12/18 10:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2014/12/18 10:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2014/12/18 10:48:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
```

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure that your function is in a package that contains this in its name:

- .functions. and doesn't contain .gui.

This is as per this property in jmeter.properties:

- classfinder.functions.contain=.functions.
- classfinder.functions.notContain=.gui.

Comment: Above two lines are already set in the `jmeter.properties`, but i am not able to find any advantage with it....:(

Comment: What is the package of your class ? Thx if it does not contains functions in its name, it won't appear as per my answer

Comment: This package is called in my code:

`package org.apache.jmeter.functions;`